# What happens behind the scenes if the parameter of srand function is an negative int?

Tags: c, random, casting, implicit-conversion, srand

The `srand man` says that `srand` has as parameter an unsignd int,
but when using without casting the compile does not complain.
Have any chance of going wrong if you do not use cast with
`(unsigned int)` ? Or not makes difference, because the compiler 
always will convert it implicitly ?

As an example, a code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int num, x;

    x = -2;

        srand(x);
    num = rand() % 100000;

    printf("%d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

The print of this code is:

```
32
```

I will assume that the compiler will implicitly convert the variable x of type `int` in `unsigned int` . 
What happens in this conversion ?
What if the conversion convert the variable (that has type `int`) to an `unsigned int`
that is the same value than an other number
that when after the seed was generated, they will be identical. 
In other words:

```
int x = -2;
int y = 546; // the number 546 is just an example !

int num_x = srand(-2);
int num_y = srand(546);
```

And, behinde the scenes, `num_x` is equal to `num_y`.

This doubt appeared when I have had a negative parameter on my srand and I was in doubt if this seed would be unique. I think is not, because for an example, the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int t, num;
    t = -6;

    printf("%u\n", t);  // prints the variable t as unsigned (implicitly converted)
        srand(t);
    num = rand() % 100000;
    printf("Random number: %d\n", num);

    srand(4294967290);   // the number 4294967290 is how the int number -6 looks like when converted in unsigned int
    num = rand() % 100000;
    printf("New random number: %d\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of it:

```
4294967290
Random number: 19
New random number: 19
```

So, always negative numbers after converted will behave like this ? 
How do I take care of this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be implicitly converted, using [-Wconversion](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion) with gcc and clang should provide a warning for this, clang gives the following warning:

```
warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
    srand(x);
    ~~~~~ ^
```

the rules used for this conversion are covered in the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.3.1.3` *Signed and unsigned integers* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> 1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
>      other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
>      is unchanged.
> 2. **Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned**, the value is converted by
>      repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>      can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>      the new type.49)
> 3. Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>      in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>      implementation-defined signal is raised.

So for your first example `-2` converted to *unsigned int* would be:

```
UINT_MAX + 1 + -2
```

which is `UINT_MAX - 1`, this leads to the useful property that `-1` will always be converted to the max unsigned value for whatever unsigned type you are using.

You can use [limits.h](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/limits.h) to get `UINT_MAX`.

The signed case is different and is covered by paragrah *3* above, it is implementation defined, which means the compiler decides how to deal with this case so you have to read the documentation if any provided to understand what will happen here. For example [implementation defined behavior section for integers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation) says for this case:

> - The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a
>     signed integer type when the value cannot be represented in an object
>     of that type (C90 6.2.1.2, C99 and C11 6.3.1.3).
>
>   *For conversion to a type of width N, the value is reduced modulo 2^N
>     to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.*

So it treats the signed case similar to the unsigned case, the number just rolls over and it does not cause a signal to be raised. So for `gcc` this is well defined behavior but this is not portable behavior and so should not be relied on.

Comment: One more question you might know, I observed that a similar behavior appears when I try to assign to an `int` variable a number greater than it supports. So, what is the calculation to know what value it will be stored on the variable wherein I tried to store a greater value than it supports ? This will help me to know how it is implemented.

Comment: First thanks for the link, will help me a lot, but, I'm sorry for the insistence, I read the documents but have not found something that showed how the number is stored case is larger than the type supports. I'd like something like the session 6.3.1.3 which reports in detail.

Comment: I think I get it. I found something on the internet saying about integer overflow. So, in this case, that's what I mean? Or integer overflow exists only when there is arithmetic involved ? [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) and [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea is correct，because in the head file "stdlib.h", the declaration
 of srand function is:

```
void srand (unsigned int seed);
```

Therefore，if you give a negative int to the srand function as a parameter, the srand functiong will convert the  negative int to unsigned int.

Here is an example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int test(unsigned int data)
{
    if(data == 4294967290)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 99;
}
int
main(void)
{
    int i;

    i = -6;
    printf("negative parameter : %d\n", test(i));

    i = 4294967290;
    printf("unsigned parameter : %d", test(i));


    return 0;
}
```

The output of it:

```
negative parameter : 1
unsigned parameter : 1
```

I hope my answer useful to you.